# Is there an simd/avx instruction to return a u8 mask for every 32 bit lane that isn't 0

Tags: c++, vectorization, simd, avx2

Say i have a 256 bit wide vector like this:

```
00000000 00000000 11100110 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 10000101 00000000
00000000 00000000 01111110 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00001100 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

What would be the most efficient way to get a 8 bit mask
that looks a little something like this: `10110010`
where every set bit represents a 32 bit integer lane that is > 0
using AVX2 and everything that both amd and intel support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming signed integer lanes:

```
inline uint8_t positiveMask_epi32( __m256i vec )
{
    // Compare 32-bit integers for i > 0
    const __m256i zero = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32( vec, _mm256_setzero_si256() );
    // Collect high bits
    const int mask = _mm256_movemask_ps( _mm256_castsi256_ps( zero ) );
    // Return that value
    return (uint8_t)mask;
}
```

If they’re unsigned integers:

```
inline uint8_t nonZeroMask_epu32( __m256i vec )
{
    // Compare 32-bit integers for i == 0
    const __m256i eqZero = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32( vec, _mm256_setzero_si256() );
    // Collect high bits
    const int mask = _mm256_movemask_ps( _mm256_castsi256_ps( eqZero ) );
    // Flip lowest 8 bits in the result, we want 1 for non-zeros
    return (uint8_t)( mask ^ 0xFF );
}
```